# What happens when a pure virtual function is called on an instance of the parent class in which it is declared?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am new to C++ and have run into an interesting problem in some code with which I have been working lately. Suppose we have the following classes: `Parent`, `Child_A`, `Child_B`, and `Child_C`:

```
class Parent {
    ...
    virtual int Foo() = 0;
    ...
}


class Child_A : Parent {
    ...
    int Foo() { return 1; }
    ...
}

class Child_B : Parent {
    ...
    int Foo() { return 2; }
    ...
}

class Child_C : Parent {
    ...
    int Foo() { return 3; }
    ...
}
```

Now I know what happens if I do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Child_A> a = std::make_unique<Child_A>();
Parent *p = &a;
p->Foo();
```

That will return 1. But my question is, what happens if I do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Parent> p = std::make_unique<Parent>();
p->Foo();
```

Thanks to anyone who can help!

**Edit: Turns out that my question does not make any sense, regardless of how many times I try to fix my syntax. A pure virtual function can't be called on the parent like that. I found out later that the code I was looking for did set the parent equal to a member of one of its child classes (with the virtual function defined) before it called that function...I had just missed it before.**

Comment: You can't instantiate `Parent` because it is abstract.  The compiler will complain if you try.  And `Parent p = a` will cause _object slicing_ (and a compiler error, probably).  I think you mean `Parent *p = &a` or similar.

Comment: You're completely correct. Edited to fix that problem, and other problems. I haven't used C in awhile and am just now learning C++, so a lot of these seemingly small details are tripping me up.

Comment: `Child_A a = new Child_A();` should be `Child_A * a = new Child_A();`(because `new` returns a pointer and you can't assign a pointer to a non-pointer) and then `Parent *p = &a;` becomes `Parent *p = a;` or you can cut right through to `Parent *p = new Child_A();`

Comment: Also, C++ isn't Java. Use `std::make_unique<Type>` instead of `new Type();`. The latter is bound to cause major issues in the future as new indicates you are personally responsible in managing the memory associated with the object.

Comment: You're totally right. I discovered by accident that the code wasn't doing what I thought it was doing, and it seems based on many answers that my question doesn't make a boatload of sense anyway. Thanks everyone for the syntax tips!

Comment: Right on page with @Isaiah here, and will go a step further. You'll find that there are large advantages to working almost entirely with Automatic variables and no dynamic allocation whatsoever. In general the preferences should go, in order: [Automatic Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable), [Library container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) or [Smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), `new`, `malloc` and family.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a little misunderstood about C++ syntax, despite the fact your classes don't inherit from parent class.

When you declare a member function like this `void foo() = 0`, you are saying that your function isn't implemented and you're making your class abstract, and you cannot instantiate an abstract class. A pure virtual function doesn't mean "return 0".

Comment: I edited my post to have the correct syntax. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to be able to instantiate a parent, you could make the function virtual (not pure virtual) and then have the children override that function.